# Installation fails when trying to create an EFI partition on an ASUS ux32vd (double SSD model)

Tags: uefi, raid, ssd

I've purchased an ASUS ux32vd Ultrabook that has 2 SSD in RAID 0 configuration. I've managed to remove Windows 8 but I can't boot in Ubuntu.

When it try to create an EFI partition the installation fails. Without the EFI partition the installation finishes but no drives are shown in BIOS Boot options.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: screenshot: Drives available during installation]

[image: screenshot: Boot loader installation options]

Comment: Did you specify the mount point for the root partition? Just that I don't see anything in that column in the first screenshot. For the EFI partition the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) says that you don't need to set a mount point since the installer will do it for you. What is the error message when the installation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to install Ubuntu on my laptop.

The installer needed (lots of) help.

In gParted:

- I removed all partitions from the RAID (/dev/mapper/isw_dadfiaad_RAID0SYS2)
- I added GPT partition table to RAID (Device -> Create partition table)
- Then I created a small partition (about 350MB) at the beginning of the disk and added the boot flag to it (Partition -> Manage flags)
- I Created an ext4 partition (about 464GB)
- I used the remaining space (about 2GB) for swap

Error messages and warnings were poping up all the time, and gParted crashed quite a few times, but eventually it worked.

During the installation I partitioned the first partition as /boot/efi and the installation was successfully completed.